# Method threw 'org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException' exception

Tags: connectionexception, executionexception, elasticsearch-exception

When I try to debug this line

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticSearchRestHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

in the code I'm getting the error as shown in screenshot, can anyone help how to resolve this.

[Screenshot of the error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfQKI.png)

I'm trying to obtaining the search response, which contains the results of the query.

Comment: Your problem is very poorly described. We don't know about how you're initializing your connection. Where the ES cluster is. Etc. Looking at the attached picture, it seems to be an issue with establishing a connection. It could also be that your cluster is overwhelmed and can't respond in time. I'd say start by providing more context and code to help us better understand the problem.